# Accessing variables declared within a function outside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm attempting to make a simple flashcard set in JavaScript and HTML. In my effort to reduce the amount of code I use (reduce redundancy)

I tried to make a function with 4 inputs

```
function displaySet(xMin, xMax, cardSelect, title)
```

This function is meant to be placed within another function. As follows:

```
$("#face_parts_basic").click(function(){
    displaySet(1,11,body_parts, "Basic Parts of a Face");
});
```

The DOM element with the id "face_parts_basic" is a clickable div which then un-hides the flashcard placeholder div. It is meant to populate it with the correct data from its proper location within the array(defined as cardSelect).

The function works as far as loading the first items within the data array goes. However when I try to cycle through with my forward and back buttons, it doesn't work. Originally I had hard coded each .click function with the values it would need to loop through. It worked fine with my forward and backwards function.

I believe the problem I am having is that the iMin & iMax variables aren't supplying the forward/backwards functions with any values. Hence why it won't cycle through.

To clarify:
xMin and xMax are meant to provide the locations of the data within my array. The iMin & iMax variables are assigned the value xMin & xMax value. These variables are then meant to be used by the #btn_fwd & #btn_bck .click functions to set the parameters for looping within my data array. This is my current code. Below it I will show how I was originally writing each function.

```
var i = 0;
var iMin;
var iMax;
var card;
var cardArray;

function name() {
  return document.getElementById("name");
}

function plural() {
  return document.getElementById("plural");
}

function type() {
  return document.getElementById("type");
}

function imgLoc() {
  return document.getElementById("imgLoc");
}

function bodyBasic() {
  return document.getElementById("body_basic");
}

function clearCont() {
  $("#card").html("");
  $("#name").html("");
  $("#plural").html("");
  $("#type").html("");
  $("#imgLoc").attr("src", "");
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#popup-content").hide();

  function openContent() {
    $("#popup-content").show("slow", function() {});
  }
  $("#close-content").click(function() {
    clearCont();
    $("#popup-content").hide("slow", function() {});
  });
  //Start of flashcard sets for clicking

  function displaySet(xMin, xMax, cardSelect, title) {
    // clearCont();
    openContent();
    i = xMin;
    iMin = xMin;
    iMax = xMax;
    cardArray = cardSelect;
    $("#card").html(title);
    name().innerHTML = cardArray[i].name;
    plural().innerHTML = "<h4 style=\"display:inline\">Plural: </h4>" + cardArray[i].plural;
    type().innerHTML = cardArray[i].type;
    imgLoc().setAttribute("src", cardArray[i].imgLoc);
  };
  $("#face_parts_basic").click(function() {
    displaySet(1, 11, body_parts, "Basic Parts of a Face");
  });

  $("#body_basic").click(function() {
    displaySet(12, 25, body_parts, "Basic Parts of the Human Body");
  });
  //Flashcard navigation functionality
  $("#btn_fwd").click(function() {

    $("#card").html(title);
    name().innerHTML = cardArray[i].name;
    plural().innerHTML = cardArray[i].plural;
    type().innerHTML = cardArray[i].type;
    imgLoc().setAttribute("src", cardArray[i].imgLoc);

    if (i >= iMax) {
      i = iMin;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  });

  $("#btn_bck").click(function() {
    $("#card").html(title);
    name().innerHTML = cardArray[i].name;
    plural().innerHTML = cardArray[i].plural;
    type().innerHTML = cardArray[i].type;
    imgLoc().setAttribute("src", cardArray[i].imgLoc);

    if (i <= iMin) {
      i = iMax;
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  });
});
```

How I was originally writing each function (It worked well, just too much redundant coding in my opinion:

```
$("#face_parts_basic").click(function(){
    openContent();
    i = 1;
    iMin = 1;
    iMax = 11;

    $("#card").html("basic parts of a face");
    name().innerHTML = body_parts[i].name;
    plural().innerHTML = "<h4 style=\"display:inline\">Plural: </h4>"+body_parts[i].plural;
    type().innerHTML = body_parts[i].type;
    imgLoc().setAttribute("src",body_parts[i].imgLoc);
});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Some of it is jQuery. Hopefully this doesn't confuse.

Comment: Why do you have such a confusing mix of regular JS and jQuery? Why do you need functions like `name` when you could just use `$("#name")`?

Comment: Your original code didn't assign to `cardArray`. Other than that, I don't see any difference with using the function.

Comment: Can you make an executable snippet that demonstrates the problem? Because it looks to me like it should work.

Comment: http://fluentlyspeak.com/basic/vocabulary/nouns/index.html# only the first two sets are what my current javascript is trying to work with.

Comment: Did you open the Javascript console and look at the errors? It's getting an error from `$("#card").html(title)`. Is this really needed in the forward/back buttons? It was already done by `displaySet()`, and it doesn't change when you use the arrow buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Take out

```
$("#card").html(title);
```

in the `#btn_fwd` and `#btn_bck` click handlers. You don't need to change the title when you're navigating through the parts, that's done by `displaySet()` when you select the category.

If you did need this, you would use another global variable, just like you do for `cardArray`.